# Change default template to 'common.volt'?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

From what I understand, Phalcon uses `index.phtml` or `index.volt` in `app/views` as the base template for any page that doesn't have a template specified.

How can I change this to use `app/views/layouts/common.volt`?

Comment: **Interface Phalcon\Mvc\ViewInterface** https://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/api/Phalcon_Mvc_ViewInterface.html?highlight=Main%20Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the view component we need to declare $view Object like the following:

```
$di->set('view', function () use ($config) {

    $view = new View();

    $view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);
    $view->setLayout('common');
......
```

using setLayout(String name) method to set default layout for app

Answer (score 3):

It uses index.volt or index.html if the latest executed action is 'index' (indexAction in the controller).

You can use a common layout by setting a 'template before' or a 'template after':

https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/controllers/ContactController.php#L7

**Update August 2016**: since the above information is no longer available in the given link, adding it here:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->view->setTemplateBefore('your-template-name');
    $this->view->setTemplateAfter('your-template-name');
}
```

More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#using-templates

Comment: Yeah but that requires manually going into every controller and setting that, plus I'm pretty sure there was one case it didn't work. Anyway, $view->setMainView('common') was what I was looking for. Thanks!